# Creating IP layer packets in PHP?

Tags: php, networking

I'm wondering if it possible to create network layer packets (i.e. define my own IP headers) using PHP? It seems like `socket_create` with `SOCK_RAW` only lets you define the contents of the IP packet, not the headers itself.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: What do you need to create raw packets for?

Comment: What OS are you working with?  root access is normally required to create raw sockets.  More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#83877

Comment: @pix0r I'm working with Mac and root access is no problem.

Comment: @Marc it's for a research project for university -- I need to adjust option fields in the IP header.

Comment: Why not use python for it? There are even some nice packages macking building of and working with packets really easy.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thank you, I decided to do it with python instead. It is indeed really simple that way!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully create a socket using `SOCK_RAW` on Mac OS X, as long as I ran the script as root.

The example I used was taken from [Jean Charles MAMMANA's ping.inc.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#80775)

I created a ping.php wrapper, and executed: `sudo ping.php www.google.com`.

Here's my ping.php wrapper:

```
<?php

$default_timeout = 15;

require("ping.inc.php");

if (count($argv) < 2) usage();

$timeout = count($argv) >= 3 ? intval($argv[2]) : $default_timeout;
$host = $argv[1];

$result = ping($host, $timeout);
if ($result < 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $g_icmp_error . "\n";
} else {
    echo "$result ms\n";
}

function usage() {
    global $argv;
    echo "Usage: {$argv[0]} <host> [timeout]\n";
    die();
}
```